# Magento: How to modify the HTML of the order confirmation page?

Tags: magento

I would like to add some HTML to the order confirmation aka checkout success page of my Magento store (the page whose url ends with index.php/checkout/onepage/success/).

Is there a way to do this from the Admin Panel? I don't see it under any of the existing menus (http://grab.by/N1Ek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *add* HTML with a widget:

1. Go to CMS > Static Blocks, create a new static block with your HTML code as content
2. Go to CMS > Widgets, add new widget instance
3. Choose type "CMS Static Block" and your theme
       [image]
4. Choose a title, select "Display on: Specified Page" and "Page: One Page Checkout Success". In "Block Reference", choose where on the page the content should be added
       [image]
5. On the "Widget Options" tab, select the static block, created in (1)
       [image]

Then clear cache and you're set.