# Modifying the HTML of product pages on Magento

Tags: magento

If I want to add to the HTML of my product pages on Magento it seems according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933682/3223841) that it can be done by modifying a template file on the file system. But I was wondering if it could also be done through the Admin console (http://grab.by/N1Ek). Perhaps with the use of static blocks and widgets as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519947/3223841)?

If it is possible to do it through the Admin console, then would changes here overwrite the template files on the file system or would changes made on the template file still be there?

Comment: Both are possible.  If you want to create a static block that will appear on all the product pages, you can create it in the admin and then edit the template file to include the static block.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @NotJay, if I have different themes each with their own template file, can I still add HTML to specific themes using only the admin console. I ask because right now I don't have access to the file system where the template files are.

Comment: There's a possibility that somewhere in the admin you can make modifications to the xml files which control the layout of the pages.  Did your theme install new sections of your admin?

Comment: Out of the box, I don't think that you can add blocks to pages, however, there might be extensions that allow you to manage this in the admin.  Do you have access to Magento Connect to install extensions?